# I need help proving that if f(n) = O(g(n)), then log f(n) = O(log g(n)) is FALSE

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

> Let functions f and g such that f(n) is O(g(n)) and following
>   statements:
>
> I. log f(n) is O(log g(n))
>   II. 2<sup>f(n)</sup> is O(2<sup>g(n)</sup>)
>   III. f(n)<sup>2</sup> is O(g(n)<sup>2</sup>)
>
> Which of the following statement(s) is/are false?
>
> A. I and II
>   B. I and III
>   C. II and III
>   D. All I, II, III
>
> Explanation:
>
> Only statement (III) f(n)<sup>2</sup> is O(g(n)<sup>2</sup>) is correct.
>
> Option (A) is true.

Solution says that only statement 3 is correct, rest 2 are wrong.

I understand that II is wrong because f(n) can be 2n and g(n) can be n; then f(n) != O(g(n)), but how is statement I false?

Comment: What am I missing? As far as I can tell, all three statements are true. Per your example, if f(n) = 2n then log f(n) = log 2n = log 2 + log n which actually is O(log n).

Comment: Most likely statement II is actually 2^f(n) is O(2^g(n))

Comment: Yeah, it shoud be 2^f(n) is O(2^g(n)). Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 2):

Statement I is false and here's why. Let f(n) = 2 and g(n) = 1. Then f(n) = O(g(n)). However, log(f(n)) = 1 and log(g(n))= 0. There is no n0 nor any c such that 1 <= c * 0.

EDIT: presumably, statement II is not formatted properly and should read 2^f(n) = O(2^g(n)), which is false if f(n) = 2n and g(n) = n, e.g.